# Detect if mouse pointer is overtop of a pseudo element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a pseudo element that is outside the bounds of the parent element:

```
#parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #ff0;
}

#parent:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #ffc;
}
```

I need to be able to detect if the mouse pointer is overtop of the pseudo element.

I looked into this a few years ago and at the time it was not possible, as pseudo elements are not a part of the DOM.

I am wondering if this has changed?  Using the latest greatest goodies in html5 / javascript, is there any (elegant) way to detect if the pointer is overtop of the pseudo element?  It seems like this is something that should be possible...

Answer (score 0):

events will still be bubble to your parent.

```
$("#parent").on("mouseover", function(){
    //on top of parent or pseudo element.
});
```

Comment: Thanks - is there any way to differentiate between the parent and the pseudo-element?