# Detect if element clicked is a pseudo element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the same situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268959/detect-if-mouse-pointer-is-overtop-of-a-pseudo-element), but it's not answered well. I have this code for a workaround:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  // sticky profile notes
  const notes = document.querySelector('#textarea-notes'); // Get textarea element
  const headerDiv = document.createElement("div"); // Create a <div> element
  headerDiv.id = 'div-header';
  headerDiv.innerHTML = 'Add Notes'; // Insert instructions

  // add header on top 
  notes.parentNode.insertBefore(headerDiv, notes);
  // minimize sticky
  headerDiv.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // detect if cursor type is pointer
    console.log(e.target.style.cursor);
  });
});
```

```css
#div-header {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  background-color: #ffffcc;
}

#div-header:after {
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  content: 'button';
}

#textarea-notes {
  background-color: #ffffcc;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea-notes">
    </textarea>
```

wherein I aim to check what type of mouse pointer the user has when clicking the div with the `div` element.

The problem is when I log the cursor type, it shows an empty space. How do I know the cursor type? And is there a better way to identify if the clicked element is a pseudo-element?

Comment: Perhaps you want to use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: I need to check if I clicked the `button`, `getComputedStyle(headerDiv)` only returns the element. Or am I missing some other function?

Comment: Why not use a different element? Pseudo elements are not actually part of the DOM so you can't detect if they are clicked, only the parent they belong to

Comment: @charlietfl, I'm using django templates and I don't know how to add HTML DOM elements using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't detect events on pseudo elements you can insert separate elements into the `headerDiv` and check the target of the click event to accomplish the same objective. (Or only apply events to the new child elements)

Here I created two spans for "add notes" and "button" texts which get appended to the new div. A new css rule for the button span applies the margin and pointer cursor

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  // sticky profile notes
  const notes = document.querySelector('#textarea-notes'); // Get textarea element
  const headerDiv = document.createElement("div"); // Create a <div> element
  headerDiv.id = 'div-header';
  
  // Create two spans to insert in headerDiv
  const notesTitle = document.createElement('span')
  notesTitle.innerHTML = 'Add Notes'; // Insert instructions
  // this span could also be a real <button>
  const notesBtn = document.createElement('span');
  notesBtn.textContent = 'button';
  notesBtn.className = 'notes-btn'
  
  headerDiv.append(notesTitle)
  headerDiv.append(notesBtn)

  // add header on top 
  notes.parentNode.insertBefore(headerDiv, notes);
  // minimize sticky
  headerDiv.addEventListener('click', e => {
     let msg = 'Parent clicked';
     if(e.target.matches('.notes-btn')){
        msg = 'Button clicked';
     }
     console.log(msg)
  });
});
```

```css
#div-header {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  background-color: #ffffcc;
}

/*#div-header:after {
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  content: 'button';
}*/

#div-header .notes-btn{
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#textarea-notes {
  background-color: #ffffcc;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea-notes">
    </textarea>
```